# 4x4 word grid optimization

Tags: optimization, letters, construction, word-square

Given that each letter in the English alphabet has a position:
$$a = 1, b = 2, ..., z = 26$$
Can you place 16 different letters such that:

- Each row, column and diagonal forms a 4-letter valid English word. You could use [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/).
- The sum of all letter positions is maximized. That is, using `able` counts as $a+b+l+e = 1+2+12+5 = 20$.

#### "And what if such a grid doesn't exist?" — @Bass

For every letter that is used twice or more, all words containing the letter won't count in the total. That is, a `beer` won't count any point alongside with all other letters in words in the grid that have an `e`.

Comment: How certain are you that it's possible to create a(n unavoidably double) word square from 16 distinct letters at all, not to even mention the diagonals?

Comment: @Bass, actually, I am not certain at all. I have improved the puzzle thanks to your relevant remark :)

Comment: Can the diagonals be read in either direction?

Comment: @hexomino, not precised in the puzzle so yes!

Answer (score 1):

The best I've found so far has a one letter repeat

> ```
>  T Y M P
>  H A I L
>  U N C O
>  S K E T
> ```

With the caveat that

> "tymp" does not appear at dictionary.com but does appear on [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tymp). I hope this is acceptable.

I'm not sure how to score this (maybe OP can advise).

Comment: I believe your score is 27, the "double letter negates all points from words using said letter" rule really reduces said score